# OpenAI Lambda Function: How to attach AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess policy or create an inline policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Working on this awesome AWS OpenAI Chat tutorial but they sometimes skip a few steps:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-openai-chatbot-demo#create-a-lambda-function-to-handle-user-login

Specifically stuck on this step and how to do it in AWS Lambda console: "This function will invoke DynamoDB service API to verify the user credentials, so we need to attach AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess policy or create an inline policy to the role of this function"

Thanks much for any help!

Googled and StackOverflowed and searched AWS docs. Looking for how to attach AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess policy to an AWS Lambda function. Maybe a link to specific docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add permissions to the role in IAM Console

Go to lambda function -> configuration tab -> Permissions -> Execution role -> Click on the role link.

It will take you to respective IAM role.

In IAM Role -> Permissions -> Add Permissions (Drop Down on right) -> Attach policies -> AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess and attach it